# How to convert .eml file to .msg file for each new item in a document library?

Tags: event-receivers, email

I have a document library. Sometimes we upload .eml files. These .eml files could not be opened on mobile devices. When you convert the .eml file to a .msg file it is possible to open the file on mobile devices.

I would like to implement something which recognize the end user is uploading a .eml file and convert it to .msg file. I thinking of a event receiver or workflow. Maybe someone can tell me what the best solution is?

.eml and .msg files are email files.

Comment: Do you upload the file or send it into the library? If you send emails into sharepoint it's just a setting in your library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a SP2010 or SP2013 on-premise version.

3 options:

- create an event handler that captures the onAdded event on the document library. In the event handler check the file extension and convert the file if necessary
- create a custom workflow. Same principle as above but put the converting logic in a workflow. A workflow is easier if you need to configure the logic to several document libraries.
- create a timerjob that checks for .eml files and converts them. Depending on the scheduele there is a delay in the conversion process.